# Enthalpy change with temperature

Tags: enthalpy

Recently I stumbled across a book that describes enthalpy change with temperature, specifically for a product of combustion process (e.g. CO as a result of solid carbon combustion). The book says that enthalpy of formation at $298$ K is $-110.5~\rm\frac{kJ}{mol}$, meaning that this is the amount of energy that gets **released** during combustion.
But in a very next paragraph there are two opposite calculation for enthalpy at 2000K: one says it is $-53~\rm\frac{kJ}{mol}$ (less energy get released during combustion), and the other it is $+167~\rm\frac{kJ}{mol}$ (the energy must be **brought into system**)?

Can you please clarify which number is correct and does energy goes out or into the system?

Comment: Well, perhaps you could summarize the 'two opposite calculations' to give us a hint about them and why they might be different?

Comment: What it says is that the enthalpy at 2000 K (value of enthalpy in the book: -53 kJ/mol or +167 kJ/mol?) is the enthalpy of formation at 298 K (value = -110 kJ/mol) + change in enthalpy from 298 K to the 2000K (value = 57 kJ/mol). My guess is that authors ment this is enthalpy for a case where CO2 had to be first produced through the combustion at referent temperature 298 K (resulting in negative enthalpy of -110 kJ/mol) and then heated to 2000 K by adding 57 kJ/mol extra energy from enviroment.  Resulting -167 kJ/mol would be just an error and -53 kJ is the right value. Does it sound ok?